# Camera projection of mesh using opengl

Tags: opengl, camera

I have a set of camera parameters (rotation, translation, focal length etc) that I have obtained from SFM pipeline. I also have a mesh in the form of ply file. For each camera, I want the projection of the mesh onto an image with respect to that camera. In other words, the output is an image of how the camera looks at the mesh. I know that I can use openGL for that, but unfortunately I have no knowledge in openGL. I looked up [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Viewing_and_Transformations#How_can_I_move_my_eye.2C_or_camera.2C_in_my_scene.3F) page for an answer, but I don't know how I can use the camera parameters in here.

Comment: You can transfer the parameters more or less directly into matrices that altogether form the transform. Focal length can be converted to field of view and then to a projection matrix. If you have absolutely no knowledge of OpenGL or algebraic geometry, you should probably start with some basic tutorials. For now, this question is way too broad. I wouldn't even know where to start explaining.

Comment: Thanks. I have started reading some tutorials about camera transformations. My main problem is converting the camera parameters to the model view matrix compatible with opengl. Is there a way I can convert the rotation and translation to model view matrix ?

Comment: You can just create rotation and translation matrices and multiply them together. In the end, you might need to invert the matrix, that depends on the nature of your parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case if someone has the same problem. I found an interesting article over the internet that solved my problem.

http://ksimek.github.io/2013/06/03/calibrated_cameras_in_opengl/

The same article also describes how we can decompose a camera matrix to intrinsic and extrinsic parameters, and how we can plug them into opengl paradigm.